# module-bluez5-device not loaded (pulseaudio)

Tags: pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez

I'm running a system wide PulseAudio daemon, which is working. Now I'd like to play audio from my phone over bluetooth.

In system.pa I'm loading module-bluetooth-policy and module-bluetooth-discover.
When I check what's loaded, I also see module-bluez5-discover is loaded.

However, I think, that what's missing is **module-bluez5-device**, which I assume is going to be the 'card' for PulseAudio. Anyway, I could manually load it, if I know the dbus address of the bluetooth device (which I don't), but I think it would normally be loaded by one of those bluetooth modules.

Which module/process loads this module and what could be reasons that it hasn't loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**module-bluez5-device is not required**.

I have audio to pulse over bluetooth now working in two environments, a Buildroot and Debian Jessie. Both don't seem to use module-bluez5-device.

Not sure what it does still, but it's apparently not required.